# length converter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, converters

[image]

I have to reproduce a length converter like the picture above. When you put a number in the box and press a button, it gives you the result on the right of the button you choose.
I started by making the buttons. Here is the code, my problem is I don't know how to make a function that returns outside the box the result of the button chosen.

```
Valeur:<input type="text" name="valeur" value="0" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)"onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)"> Resultat ici<br>
<button type="button" id="inchToCm" onclick="pvc()">Pouces vers cm</button>
<button type="button" id="cmtoInch">CM vers pouces</button>
<button type="button"id="celciusToFarenheit">Celcius vers
Farenheit</button>
    <button type="button" id="farenheitToCelcius">Farenheit vers Celcius</button>
```

I started making the function to do the length conversion:

```
<script>
function pvc(valnum){
    document.getElementById("outputCm").innerHTML=valnum/0.39370;
}

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Is there an element within `html` which has `id` set to `"outputCm"`?

Comment: No there isnt. @guest271314

Comment: At which element is result expected to be appended to `document`? Note, no parameter is passed to `pvc()` call at event attribute call, where `pvc` function body expects `valnum` parameter.

Comment: so i need to put pvc(valnum) is that what youre saying ?

Comment: The element defined at `javascript` function should reference element defined in `html` `document`. The function expects a parameter to be passed.Yes, pass variable to `pvc()` call.  Is `valnum` expected to be user input?

Comment: yes valnum is the number to be converted in the function

Comment: Where is `valnum` defined?

Comment: I just realised its not. how can i declare it so it takes the user inputs value?

Comment: Are you trying to get user input at the same user input from  `<input>` element where `LengthConverter(this.value)` is set at value of `oninput` and `onchange` attributes?

Comment: Im trying to get the user input to be converted when user presses a button, lets say inch to cm. When pressed, result is printed outside next to a <p> that says Results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a p element for "Resultat ici" with an id so that the value can be retrieved from the user.

```
Valeur:<input type="text" id="value" name="valeur" value="0" /> 

<p id="result">Resultat ici</p>

<button type="button" id="inchToCm" onclick="pvc()">Pouces vers cm</button>
<button type="button" id="cmtoInch" onclick="pvc()">CM vers pouces</button>
<button type="button"id="celciusToFarenheit" onclick="pvc()">Celcius vers
Farenheit</button>
<button type="button" id="farenheitToCelcius" onclick="pvc()">Farenheit vers 
Celcius</button>
```

I did the first conversion for you in the below code:

```
<script>
     function pvc() {  
        //get user's input
      var input = document.getElementById("value").value;

     /*implement if statement tests here for the next 3 buttons
      (cmtoinch, celctofahr, fahrtocelc)
      */

      //result of the calculation that is then put into the result p element with the id of result.
      var result = document.getElementById("result");
      result.innerHTML = input / 0.39370;

    }
</script>
```

Also, here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/MmeXxR

Update: codepen includes if statement

Comment: It is working! Ill use your example for the rest. I still have a lot of struggle understanding basic javascript and your answer helped me. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I was glad to help. I am learning as well. Here are some good websites for learning javascript: teamtreehouse.com, freecodecamp.com, codecademy.com, udacity.com

Comment: can i ask you... i still dont understand... i created the function  function cvp{
        var input=document.getElementById("value").value;
        var result1 = document.getElementById("result1");
        result1.innerHTML = input * 0.39370;
    
}  but i still cant have it print. the first one you did worked but not this one.

Comment: what would the if statement look like ?

Comment: I updated the codepen to include a possible if statement. This if statement compared the parameter of the function, and the parameter of the function is input by the "onclick" events in the HTML. Add the new calculations for each button where you need them in the if statement: https://codepen.io/capozzic1/pen/MmeXxR

Comment: Thanks a lot for the codepen, I updated the code with the formulas but when I try it it doesnt work. Ive updated the IF statements with the calculations, but when i press the buttons nothing happens.

Comment: function pvc(val){
  var input = document.getElementById("value").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  if (val == 'inch') {  
  result.innerHTML = input / 0.39370;
  console.log(val);
  } else if (val == 'cm') { 
  
  result.innerHTML = input * 0.39370;
  
  } else if (val == 'celc') {   
  result.innerHTML = * 9 / 5 + 32
  } else if (val == 'fahr') {   
  result.innerHTML = (farenheit – 32) * 5 / 9 
  
  }
}

Comment: I think the code is right I just dont understand why it doesnt return the result